# Cypher query to list nodes with same relationship attribute

Tags: graph, neo4j, nosql, cypher

I'm learning Nosql and I'm using Neo4j Sandbox, here are my queries to create my nodes and relationships between them :

```
CREATE (n0:Student { nb: '0', name: 'A' })
CREATE (n1:Student { nb: '1', name: 'B' })
CREATE (n2:Student { nb: '2', name: 'C' })
CREATE (n3:Student { nb: '3', name: 'D' })
CREATE (n4:Student { nb: '4', name: 'E' })

CREATE (c1:Course { course_nb: '1', course_name: 'Cryptography' })
CREATE (c2:Course { course_nb: '2', course_name: 'Big Data' })
CREATE (c3:Course { course_nb: '3', course_name: 'Cloud' })

CREATE (n1)-[:Follow]->(c1)
CREATE (n2)-[:Follow]->(c1)
CREATE (n3)-[:Follow]->(c1)
CREATE (n3)-[:Follow]->(c2);
```

I want to list the students nodes who are related to the same course_nb or course_name attribute

```
Result should be : 
    ╒------------------╤-------------------- -╕
    |  "Students.name" | "Courses.course_name"|
    -------------------|-----------------------
    "B"                | "Cryptography"
    "C"                | "Cryptography"
    "D"                | "Cryptography"
```

I've tried this query :

```
MATCH(n:Course)<-[r:Follow]-(name)
RETURN n
```

This return all the courses related to Students nodes, I've also tried some queries with WHERE and WITH statement but without success

Basically I want to list the students who follow the same course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all students related to a course, either by applying a `course_nb` filter in the `MATCH` clause, like this:

```
MATCH(n:Course{course_nb: '1'})<-[r:Follow]-(person:Student)
RETURN  person.name, n.course_name
```

Or, you should group the students by course name, and only select the courses, having more than one student, like this:

```
MATCH(n:Course)<-[r:Follow]-(person:Student)
WITH n.course_name AS cname, COLLECT(person.name) AS persons WHERE size(persons) > 1
UNWIND persons AS personName
RETURN cname, personName
```

Comment: fixed a typo on person:Student. thanks.